# jenkins android build failed :"Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseAidl'",but build with androidstudio is Ok,Could someone tell me why

Tags: android, jenkins, aidl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseAidl'.

  > java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process D:\android\sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aidl.exe with arguments {-pD:\android\sdk\platforms\android-26\framework.aidl -oC:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\workspace\SilverfoxApp\app\build\generated\source\aidl\release -IC:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\workspace\SilverfoxApp\app\src -IC:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\workspace\SilverfoxApp\app\src\release\aidl -IC:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-media-compat-26.1.0.aar\159028b5cebd5c0f843dcb73fb68d3b7\aidl -IC:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-26.1.0.aar\c6e91035c6b1aafcae56340d2f01e4a5\aidl -dC:\Windows\TEMP\aidl62401336013464191.d C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\workspace\SilverfoxApp\app\src\main\aidl\com\cn\silverfox\silverfoxwealth\service\INoticeService.aidl}
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Check jenkins server bind-util and bind-lib version first